# Using startswith() with strings formatting operators

Tags: python-2.7, formatting, startswith

I have the following bits of code:

```
name = "Axe"
vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]    

if %s.startswith(vowels) % (name):    #name will be input from users
    print "sth"
else:
    ....
```

Here, I try to use the startswith function with strings formatting operators but it didn't work. I also tried with the {} format, but it still gives me a syntax error.
Am I doing something wrong or this isn't possible?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear from your code exactly what you mean to do, but this works:

```
>>> ("%s" % 'hi').startswith('h')
True
```

So I think that the problem is that you have to first format your string and then do `.startswith()`. Also I don't think that `startswith` accepts arrays as an argument so you would have to do something like

```
if True in map(lambda x: ("%s" % name).startswith(x), vowels):
    # do something
```

And furthermore if you want to ignore case you would do:

```
if True in map(lambda x: ("%s" % name).lower().startswith(x), vowels):
    # do something
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you! 
And yes, you're right. It gave me an error because I was working with a list, so I turned it into a tuple to use your first suggestion. However, if I really needed to use a list, your second option works as well! :)